# BackboneJS Add and remove class to clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have this Backbone App where I fetch a JSON file, which displays the alphabetletters, when clicking on one of those letters, it will display the relevant Artists starting with that letter. It works so far but what I want to achieve is to add some kind of `active`-class to the clicked letter. How can i achieve this?

My View looks like this:

```
function (App, Backbone) {

    var Alphabet = App.module();
    var LetterView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: 'alphabetlist',
        tagName: 'li',  
        serialize: function() {
            return this.model.toJSON();
        },  

    });

    Alphabet.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ol',
        className: 'alist',
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', this.render);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.onSync);

            this.collection.fetch();
        }, 
        beforeRender: function() {
            var self = this;

            this.collection.each(function(item) {
                self.insertView(new LetterView({model: item}))
            })
        },
    });
    Alphabet.AlphabetCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: 'js/json/AlphabetCollection.json'
    });

    return Alphabet;
}
```

So can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance...

**EDIT**

When I do:

```
    events: {
        'click a' : 'toggle'
    },

    serialize: function() {
        return this.model.toJSON();
    },

    toggle: function(event) {
        this.$el.parent().addClass('test');
    },
```

the `<ol>`-element gets the class, but still not targetting the `<li>`-element...

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this.

```
var LetterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: 'alphabetlist',
    tagName: 'li',
    events : {
        "click li" : "toggle"
    },  
    serialize: function() {
        return this.model.toJSON();
    },  

    toggle : function(e){
        var active = $(e.currentTarget);
        active.addClass('active');
        $('li').not(active).removeClass('active');
    }

});
```

Comment: hmm no, this seems not to work 100%! In my `<li>`-elements there are `<a href>`-elements, so `"click a"` - works, but adds no class..

Comment: please create fiddle.

Comment: then you can change "click a" to  "click" - that will catch click on view $el.

Comment: @SHT + change e.tagret to e.currentTarget + $('li').not(active).removeClass('active')

Comment: hmm strange, its not responding at all. Instead of `li` I changed it to `a` since its actually a `<a href>` which is been clicked...